# Potree get WGS84 coordinates of a clicked point

Tags: javascript, coordinates, viewer, wgs84

---

Sorry for the dumb question, but I'm new in the Potree world :-D
I would like to get the WGS84 coordinates of a point clicked on a pointcloud though potree viewer.
Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use proj4

```
var firstProjection = '+proj=lcc +lat_1=44.10000000000001 +lat_0=44.10000000000001 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.999877499 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs';
var secondProjection = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ";
var coord = proj4(firstProjection,secondProjection,[point.position.x,point.position.y]);
```

pute this code on the drop function existing in addMarker function on the potree.js

Comment: Thank u. I will try it.